# React-Router How to access to useParams in custom private route

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

How can I access `useParams` in my custom private route? Private route is written to check for authentication purposes. Right now I am getting undefined.
 Code:

```
interface RegistrationToken {
  registration_token: string;
}

import React from 'react';
import { Route, Redirect } from 'react-router-dom';
import { useSelector } from 'react-redux';
import { RootState } from '../redux/rootReducer';
import Loading from '../layout/Loading';

const PrivateRoute = ({ component: Component, ...rest }: any) => {
  const isAuthenticated: boolean = useSelector(
    (state: RootState) => state.user.isAuthenticated,
  );
  const isPending = useSelector((state: RootState) => state.user.isPending);
  const { registration_token } = useParams<RegistrationToken>();

  return (
    <Route
      {...rest}
      render={(props) => {
        if (!isAuthenticated && isPending) {
          return <Loading />;
        } else if (!isAuthenticated) {
          return <Redirect to="/signin" />;
        } else {
          return <Component {...props} />;
        }
      }}
    />
  );
};
export default PrivateRoute;
```

App.tsx:

```
<Switch>
        <PrivateRoute exact path='/:registration_token/sign-up' component={SignUp} />
</Switch>
```

Comment: what's undefined exactly? also your code doesn't have `useParams` anywhere

Comment: Sorry, I have updated. I will provide screenshot from debugger

Comment: spelling error? `registraction_token` ?

Comment: I find that in order to access, component should be child. But In that case how to make it private?

Comment: @azium I checked there is no spelling error

Comment: @azium If I change from `PrivateRoute` to default `Route`, it is possible to access

Comment: oh I see because the route is nested. screw params then just grab what you want using `location.pathname` ? useparams is just for convenience. if you wanted to you could wrap your PrivateRoute in a route but that seems wasteful

Comment: @azium I got `"/c123c123c/sign-up"`. Is it okay to parse it using string manipulation or there is better way?. I think I should create a code sandbox next time.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/230282/discussion-between-jasurbek-nabijonov-and-azium).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that, in order to accesss you should wrap the component into `<Route>` otherwise, you cannot access with `useParamas()` because in my case it was undefined.
But there is solution, using `useLocation()`
in my private route:

```
const location = useLocation();
const registration_token = getRegistrationTokenFromLocation(location.pathname);
```

where `getRegistrationTokenFromLocation`. **Logic is to parse path and get desired values** in my case is localhost:3000/:registration_token/sign-up:

```
export function getRegistrationTokenFromLocation(pathName: string) {
  const firstRange = pathName.indexOf('/');
  const secondRange = pathName.indexOf('/', firstRange + 1);
  return pathName.slice(firstRange + 1, secondRange);
}
```